# HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type

Tags: java, json, resteasy, postman

POST operation to the REST service with JSON body returning

> org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException
>
> : Cannot consume content type exception

Both `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` and `@Consumes("application/json")` returned same exception.

I tried calling the service using Postman API client.

[image]

```
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@POST   
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/auth")
public Response login(UserCl usr){

    if(usr.getUsername().compareTo("user") == 0 && 
                usr.getPassword().compareTo("pass") == 0){                      
        return Response.status(200).build(); 
    }
    else{
        return Response.status(401).build();
    }

}

12:44:07,322 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed executing POST user-service/auth: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:117) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:33) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SimpleSegment.matchSimple(SimpleSegment.java:44) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:327) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:307) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:173) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:118) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have not set the `Content-Type` header. Don't remember what the default is, but you can look in the Chrome developer tools to see the full request with headers.

The <kbd>JSON</kbd> value in the drop-down is only for syntax highlighting. It doesn't actually set the header. So just add the header

```
Content-Type   ->>   application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Content-Type Header. If Content-type is missing or is different required from server, this problem has occurred.